# BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I'm currently developing e2e test for an angular application. Before running my test suites, I have to manually start backend(.net application) - my idea was to automate this undertaking.

I came across the node module opener and child_process. I wrote a file which I make npm execute in preprotractor. There are three further files, two of them move folders from a server to my desktop and the other makes a http post request to my backend.

The application opens up before my selenium standalone server is started. I then get the following error notification:

Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.0.1.56:62023/wd/hub
[launcher] BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

Does anyone of you have any ideas or tips of how to solve this problem?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "xxx",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "karma": "~0.10",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^1.5.x",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^1.x",
    "fs-extra": "^0.12.0",
    "pix-diff": "^1.0.4",
    "blink-diff": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start test/karma.conf.js  --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver && node backend.js",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + cat('app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need to post your `package.json` to get a helpful answer here.  

I would also suggest that you break down the problem into simpler pieces: first try to get the backend running via a simple script (node or otherwise) and then execute that script in your `preprotractor` script in package.json

Comment: If you just do `npm run preprotractor`, does that succeed in starting the server that you need to run your test? Does the `backend.js` script exit before the backend server is ready to accept connections? It sounds like there may be a race-type dependency between the components you are trying to run.

Comment: No, the server does not start up. I like to start the server automatically within backend.js before running protractor. Concerning your second question, how am I exactly to find out? I see the backend open up...

Answer (score 1):

it can be caused because callback function was not called in your test

```
this.Given(/^Step description$/, function (callback) {
// callback is not called
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like that than remove it from hooks

```js
this.AfterFeatures(function() {
  browser.close(); // not required
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, your backend.js probably made a request to start the server, but never waited for it to start, since protractor is starting before your backend is ready.

What you want is probably (pseudo-code):

```
requestBackendStart();
while(backend.getState !== 'started') {
  wait
}
```

to ensure that your backend is ready before you exit the script.

Comment: I'm not getting the problem when I'm running a specific protractor test suite. Only when all test suites are run, I seem to get the error notification

Comment: Sorry, but there could be too many elements at play here when you changed which test suites to run: timing changes, the way some of your test suites interact with the server, etc. I cannot provide any more info based on what is current given. I suggest you debug a little further to find a concrete issue (i.e. did the server start at the time of test run, etc) and create another question with specific questions

Comment: I debugged a little further and found out that my 'suites' definition in my protractor-config seems to be causing the error. I currently have two test suites and only the first one works if I run them individually - the second suites causes the error (I changed their order - same phenomenon). When running the tests as a whole, the backend opens up as well as the browser. However, before the browser opens the url adress, the e2e test crashed. Any ideas left?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The only actionable observations you've given me is that "one of your suite is erring out before opening url". That's not a lot of information to work with. What are your spec file, conf file? Which line is crashing? Have you tried removing other lines to identify the minimal case?  What are the errors being thrown?

Comment: I solved the problem by putting my test suites in [] brackets - looks like commas are not enough...

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was calling `process.exit()` from within my `protractor.conf.js`, killing the process before protractor had cleaned itself up.